# C# string becoming empty

Tags: c#, string, locks

Relatively new to C# and coding in general (first post here). I have a WinForms local application where some information is displayed to the user in a ReadOnly(true) RichTextBox. Almost all my classes need to send information to that RichTextBox. To simplify this process, I created a method inside a static class that uses a locked delegate to send the information to that RichTextBox. Here is a sample:

```
static class MyClass
{
    public delegate void MessageReceivedEventHandler(string message);
    public static event MessageReceivedEventHandler messageReceivedEventHandler;

    public static void MessageBox(string message)
    {
        lock (messageReceivedEventHandler)
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(20);
            messageReceivedEventHandler?.Invoke(message);
        }
    }
}
partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        MyClass.messageReceivedEventHandler += OnMessageReceived;
    }

    private void OnMessageReceived(string message)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(0, $" {message}\n");
    }
    private void Button1_click()
    {
        MyClass.MessageBox("This should be working!");
        //Add more work here...
    }
}
```

The code above would simply print "This should be working!" inside the RichtTextbox.

The problem is the text from richTextBox1 sometimes becoming empty. This issue seems to appear when the MessageBox method is being called in rapid succession. My assumption was that since I have diffent Tasks running at the same time (in other parts of my code), it probably is two Tasks attempting to use the same static ressource, hence the use of Lock. But I still have the issue.

Adding the Thread.Sleep(20) seems to fix the problem, but that is far from elegant/robust. It starts breaking up again when the time inside Sleep is <10ms.

Edit 1:
To clarify what I mean by "string becoming empty", it means the text from richTextBox1 is == "" at some points, which should not happen since the code is always inserting the text, not replacing it. The OnMessageReceived method is the only place where action is taken on the RichTextBox text.

Edit 2:
I saw many questions related to the other tasks running. First, yes it is a multi-threaded application. The only relation between those tasks and my main form is the "print" function I wrote above. To give more context, this application is used to control the position of stepper motors relative to an electrical signal. When doing so, I need to print important information in my main form. This is why losing the information in my RichTextBox (where I print the information) is an issue. The possible reason of why I am losing the text inside that RichTextBox should be the focus of this thread.

Keep in mind that this is a personnal side project, and not a large scale application.

Thanks,
Laurent

Comment: Don't use a global event handler to begin with. What are you trying to do? Whatever it is, a global event handler is *not* the solution

Comment: Define "become empty". Perhaps you're printing a lot of empty strings, pushing the text out of the view. Or perhaps you're refreshing it so often, that the UI can't keep up. The Thread.Sleep() working suggests the latter. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233377/prevent-flashing-whilst-typing-copying-to-rich-text-box

Comment: If you want two different parts of your application to communicate in a pub/sub manner, use a `Channel`. Not a global event handler. If you want to report progress or any other event across threads, use the `Progress<T>` class

Comment: shouldn't the lock be on the resource. in this case the richTextBox1 object?

Comment: What is your real use case? This example is a poor use of events.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, I will have to look into what a "Channel" is. The global event handler simply was the only solution I found to have communicatio between the main form class (which is an instance I can't seem to access any other way) and other classes.

Comment: @Laurent that's not a solution at all. You can use eg a queue or a list, or any other container to communicate between objects. If you use an `ObservableCollection` you'd get an event each time an item was added or removed in a collection

Comment: WinForms is not thread-safe. You must use `Invoke()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if his application is simple there's no need for any of that. As Charlieface said it just requires invoking back to the UI thread to set the text.  The message pump for the window will synchronize it.

Comment: @MikeJ there's no thread in the question. And Invoke is definitely not needed when there are no background threads. The OP is already using `Invoke()` anyway, to execute the event handler

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there is in your comment.  The OP is using Invoke to use the event he's setup.  He should be using it in his message received method.

Comment: @Laurent if you want to report progress, the easiest way is to use the [Progress<T>](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/#async-progress-example) class, not a global event handler.

Comment: @Laurent what are you trying to do? What are the tasks involved? .NET itself already has classes for reporting progress (Progress<T>) or implementing cross-thread pub/sub messaging  (ActionBlock<T>, Channel) with minimal coding

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code.

First, you should not lock on a public object, since that allows other threads to lock on the same object, risking interlocking your threads. Second, your symptoms suggest multiple threads are trying to access the ressources. Rather than depending on complex thread locking code, you'd rather schedule UI operations on the UI context, which will allow calling adding message from background tasks.

The best way to do that is to that is by using `Control.BeginInvoke()`

You can't copy your form instance everywhere, so we'll expose a static method. You could make the class a singleton, but if you need multiple instances that won't work. I'll give a more versatile example. When the static method is called, you don't have access to the form instance anymore, so we'll use IOC pattern with an event and delegate.

Let's make a private static event that all instances will register a callback to in the constructor. When the static method raises the static event, all instances callback will be called. The callback will schedule a modification of its text box.

```
partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private class MessageWriteRequestedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Message { get; }
        public MessageWriteRequestedEventArgs(string message)
        {
            Message = message;
        }
    }

    private static event EventHandler<MessageWriteRequestedEventArgs> MessageWriteRequested;

    public MyForm()
    {
        MessageWriteRequested += OnMessageWriteRequested;
    }

    public static void WriteMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageWriteRequested?.Invoke(this, new MessageWriteRequestedEventArgs(message));
    }

    private void OnMessageWriteRequested(object sender, MessageWriteRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.BeginInvoke(() => WriteMessageSafe(e.message));            
    }

    private void WriteMessageSafe(string message)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(0, $" {message}\n");
    }

    private void Button1_click()
    {
        // you're on ui context, you're safe to access local ui resources
        WriteMessageSafe("This should be working!");
        // if you have multiple MyForm instances, you need to use the event
        WriteMessage("Broadcasting my tralala");
    }
}
```

If you need to write to the textbox from anywhere else :

```
// do stuff
MyForm.WriteMessage("Ho Ho Ho !");
```

Comment: Hello Arwyn, thanks for taking the time to answer. This will show you how green I am in this field. I did not realize that I could simply create a single static method inside my main instanced form...it simplifies a lot of things. On another note, I am not sure why you are creating a private class to pass the message, instead of simply creating a delegate with your event (which is less code). I guess that is the IOC pattern (which I don't grasp yet) and it is "safer" than a delegate?

Comment: Hello Laurent, IOC is simply a design pattern that is implemented with events and delegates in C#. Other language do not have access to that semantic, so you'd have to do the event wiring by hand, usually using an interface and storing a collection of instances to call back.

Comment: You could definitely use a custom delegate with only string parameter, that would work fine. It is a good practice, though, to implement the standard .NET pattern for all events, that's a habit. Sometimes you'll need to ignore the event if `sender == this`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/event-pattern

Answer (score -1):

.NET already includes a class for reporting progress (or any other information) from an asynchronous operation in a thread-safe manner, [Progress< T>](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/#async-progress-example). It doesn't need locking and even better, it decouples the sender and receiver. Many long-running BCL operations accept an `IProgress<T>` parameter to report progress.

You haven't explained what's going on in the form, or what task is reporting the data. Assuming the producer is another method in the same form, you could create a `Progress<T>` instance in the same method that starts the async operation, eg :

```
async void Button1_Click()
{
    var progress=new Progress<string>(ReportMessage);

    ReportMessage("Starting");
    await Task.Run(()=>SomeLongOp(progress));
    ReportMessage("Finished");
}

void SomeLongOp(IProgress<string> progress)
{

    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    {
        ...
        progress.Report($"Message {i}");
        ...
    }

}

void ReportMessage(string message)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(0, $" {message}\n");
}
```

By using `IProgress< T>`, the `SomeLongOp` method isn't tied to a specific form or global instance. It could easily be a method on another class

**Publishing lots of messages**

Let's say you have a *lot* of workers, doing a lot of things, eg monitoring a lot of devices, and want all of them to publish messages to the same `Log` textbox or RTF box. `Progress< T>` "simply" executes the reporting delegate or event handler on its original sync context. It doesn't have an asynchronous `Report` method, nor can it queue messages. In a really high-traffic environment, the synchronization switch can delay all workers.

The built-in answer to this is to use one of the pub/sub classes like [ActionBlock< T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=net-5.0) or a [Channel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/).

An [ActionBlock< T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0) processes the messages in its input queue in order, using a worker task that runs on the ThreadPool by default. This can be changed by specifying a different `TaskScheduler` in its execution options. By default, its input queue is unbounded.

One could use an `ActionBlock` to receive messages from multiple workers and display them on a textbox. The block can be created in the constructor, and passed to all workers as an `ITargetBlock<T>` interface :

```
ActionBlock<string> _logBlock;

public MyForm()
{

    var options=new ExecutionDataFlowBlockOptions {
        TaskScheduler=TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    };
    _block=new ActionBlock<string>(ReportMessage,options);

}
```

Now the fun begins. If the workers are created by the form itself, the workers can publish to the block directly :

```
public async void Start100Workers_Click(...)
{
    var workers=Enumerable.Range(0,100)
                          .Select(id=>DoWork(id,_block));
    await Task.WhenAll(workers);
}

async Task DoWork(int id,ITargetBlock<string> logBlock)
{
    .....
    await logBlock.SendAsync(message);
    ...
}
```

Or the block could be exposed through a public property, so other classes/forms in the application can post to it.

```
public ITargetBlock<string> LogBlock=>_block;
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm going to show a simple way to do what I think you're after.

I started with a .NET Core 3.1 Win forms application.  I added a rich text control to the form.  I added a button to the form.

I added a TaskCompletionSource as a instance property - this will be used to control the tasks acting as workers which you described.

> CancellationTokenSource sharedCancel = new CancellationTokenSource();

I created an interface to represent something that accepts messages as you described:

```
public interface IMyMessageSink
{
    Task ReceiveMessage(string message);
}
```

I made my form support this interface.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMyMessageSink
```

The ReceiveMessage method looks like this:

```
    public Task ReceiveMessage(string message)
    {
        if(this.sharedCancel == null || this.sharedCancel.IsCancellationRequested)
            return Task.FromResult(0);

        this.Invoke(new Action<Form1>((s) => this.richTextBox1.Text = this.richTextBox1.Text.Insert(0, $"{message}\n")), this);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

You'll see the Invoke handles the synchronization back to the UI thread.

This should probably use BeginInvoke and then convert the APM to async tasks which you can read about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types).  But for an SO answer the above simple code will suffice.

Also note there's no error handling.  You'll want to add that to your generator and to the button handler.

Next I created a class to represent something that creates messages.  This class takes the interface created and the cancellation token. It looks like this:

```
public class MyMessageGenerator
{
    CancellationToken cancel;
    IMyMessageSink sink;

    public MyMessageGenerator(CancellationToken cancel, IMyMessageSink sink)
    {
        this.cancel = cancel;
        this.sink = sink;
    }

    public async Task GenerateUntilCanceled()
    {
        try
        {
            while (!this.cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await sink.ReceiveMessage(this.GetHashCode().ToString());
                await Task.Delay(5000, this.cancel);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        { }
    }
}
```

In the button handler we create the message generators.

```
    async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (null == this.sharedCancel)
            return;

        await Task.Run(() => new MyMessageGenerator(this.sharedCancel.Token, this).GenerateUntilCanceled());
    }
```

Finally I added an override for the form closing event:

```
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != this.sharedCancel)
        {
            this.sharedCancel.Cancel();
            this.sharedCancel.Dispose();
            this.sharedCancel = null;
        }

        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
```

If the application becomes larger and more complex you would likely benefit by adding services exposed using a DI container.  You can read about adding DI to a winforms app [here](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/dependency-injection-windows-form-desktop-app-net-core/).

Comment: This is pointless. `ReceiveMessage` is a synchronous method that returns a completed task. There's no need for `Invoke` at all. If it actually performed an asynchronous operation, `await` would return execution back to the UI thread. There's no need for `Invoke` since 2012 when `async/await` were introduced

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,  You mean besides the part where it uses Task.Run so that ReceiveMessage is called from a different thread?

Comment: The question has no `Task.Run`. This code is overcomplicated and mixes up different patterns. If you use `Task.Run`, you get back to the UI thread with `await`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos did you read the part where he says he has two different tasks running at the same time? From this I assume he has a threaded application.

Comment: Did you read the part about `await` getting you back to the UI thread? There's no need for `Invoke`. It's been replaced by `await` since 2012. In fact, if one wanted to report progress, `Progress<T>` does that already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos where would you suggest I await?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  it's wrong to say Invoke has been replaced by await.  this is only true if you're awaiting - on the UI thread - a result from a task running on a different thread.

Comment: `await` returns execution to the original synchronization context, no matter how the task was created. In a desktop application (Winforms, WPF *and* Blazor WASM) that context is the UI thread. It doesn't matter if the task itself runs on a thread, or it represents an IO task that's not using a thread

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry I should have said synchronization context instead of thread.  the point remains the same.  ConfigureAwait(false), or a null synchronization context puts you back on the thread pool. Starting from a thread pool thread gives you no way to await back to the UI context.  Progress<T> for example simply captures the current context.

Comment: So don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in the top-level `await`. Downstream `await`s don't affect where the top-level returns. What `ConfigureAwait(false)` does is **not** configure the return to the original synchronization context. There's a reason people don't use `Invoke` or such complicated code any more

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're intentionally missing the point.  await is not a replacement for Invoke. Progress<T> does solve the problem as it's doing essentially the exact same thing I laid out.  It's just generalized the invoke piece - it's posting to the sync context.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you posted an answer that is doing almost the exact same thing as this answer.  Only it doesn't handle killing the ongoing tasks and it's using a built in class to get back to the UI thread.